# How to add 2 dates in Oracle sp?

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

How can we add two dates in oracle? For example in sql we can do this, " date_1 + date_2 " how can we achieve the same thing in Oracle

Comment: How do you define the sum of two date? What should one expect from `'1999-12-31' + '2012-10-18'`?

Comment: What `sql` are you referring to? Adding two dates is meaningless. You can add an interval to a date.

Comment: What the result you want by summing 2 dates?

Comment: Which is the expected result when adding two dates? How would you add dates?

Comment: the right way is to convert 1 date into number
but when i convert date into number
i see an other exception
in oracle query

Comment: What would the number mean? Like I said, you need an interval, not a date. Is the number a number of days? Months? Years? Seconds?

Comment: As several people have said, your question is meaningless.  Yet you persistently refuse to explain what is you are trying to achieve.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding two dates together would be meaningless but you can add an interval to a timestamp. For example, to add 1 year and 10 months to a timestamp:

```
SELECT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1-10' YEAR TO MONTH FROM DUAL;
```

You can also add days to a `DATE` column using simple arithmetics. For example, you can add 45 days to the current date using:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + 45 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: For example, SELECT SYSDATE + TO_NUMBER(1) FROM DUAL this works. It will give the result as Oct 19.

But these 2 do not compile

SELECT SYSDATE + SYSDATE FROM DUAL (has problem with the +)
SELECT SYSDATE + TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL (has invalid number issue)

Comment: What's the expected result of `SELECT SYSDATE + SYSDATE FROM DUAL`?

Comment: we want to do the following:  Oct 18,2012 + Oct 19, 2012

Comment: with result being Oct. 20, 2012

Comment: /-----------------------------------

Comment: How Oct 18,2012 + Oct 19, 2012 makes Oct. 20, 2012 is beyond my understanding... what about Oct 1,2012 + Oct 19, 2012?